# Wordpress pagination for post name not working

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I'm really stumped with this pagination problem with my custom Wordpress theme.

I have a custom page which views a list of 'books'. Everything displays correctly even the pagination. My permalink option is set to 'post name'. So when I want to see page 2 of my book list, I click on the '2' and I'm led to www.domain.com/book-list/page/2 which gives me a 404 error. However, when I change my permalink option to 'default', pagination works with ?paged=2.

I've searched for 2 days and I tried many different things but none seem to work. Would appreciate any kind of help.

Here are my methods from function.php:

```
function get_book_posts($type, $num, $category = ""){

  $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => $type, 
    'posts_per_page' => $num, 
    'paged' => $paged, 
    'category_name' => $category);

    $new_query = new WP_Query($args);
    query_posts($args);
}

function get_book_pagination(){
    $args = array(
      'prev_text'    => __('&lt;'),
      'next_text'    => __('&gt;'));

  echo paginate_links($args);}
```

From booklist.php

```
<?php $posts = get_book_posts('book', 6); ?>

<?php if(have_posts()):?>

<?php while (have_posts()):the_post()?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<div class="pagination">
    <?php get_book_pagination(); ?>
</div>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the the reading settings and make it default to 2 posts, after that again make the default permalink to custom permalink and your problem will be solved.

Comment: Hi, I tried setting permalink to default and changed reading default to 2 posts and then changed the permalink back to postname, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: ohh, can you give a website page. so i can check and provide some more solution.

Comment: The site isn't up yet but I printed out my wp_query object in my 404 file. I'm not sure if it helps but it goes like this: 

WP_Query Object ( [query] => Array ( [page] => /3 [book] => page [post_type] => book [name] => page ) [query_vars] => Array ( [page] => 3 [book] => page [post_type] => book.

It's much longer but everything else is 0

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<?php $posts = get_book_posts('post', 2); ?>
            <?php if(have_posts()):?>
            <?php while (have_posts()):the_post()?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <div class="pagination">
                <?php 
                global $wp_query;
                get_book_pagination(); ?>
            </div>
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>          
            <?php endif; ?>
```

**function.php**

```
function get_book_posts($type, $num, $category = "")
{

  $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => $type, 
    'posts_per_page' => $num, 
    'paged' => $paged, 
    'category_name' => $category);

    $new_query = new WP_Query($args);
    query_posts($args);

}

function get_book_pagination(){
    global $wp_query;   
    $args = array(
      'prev_text'    => __('&lt;'),
      'next_text'    => __('&gt;'),    
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
      );

  echo paginate_links($args);
 }
```

Comment: Sorry not error but my pagination is still not working. I've printed my wpquery on my 404 page and this is what I got: WP_Query Object ( [query] => Array ( [page] => /3 [book] => page [post_type] => book [name] => page ) [query_vars] => Array ( [page] => 3 [book] => page [post_type] => book.

Comment: try to set permalink from permalink setting menu on admin side

Comment: Hi yes I've changed the permalink from the admin side. I tried using the debug plugin and it prints my query as: [request] => SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND (wp_posts.ID = '0') AND wp_posts.post_type = 'book'  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC. Is there a reason why my ID is 0 and how do I change it?

Comment: i had try above code in function.php and it works fine...with select pastname as permalink

Comment: Hi vrajesh thanks for the help. The code looks right to me as well. I'm not familiar with wordpress and this theme was programmed by someone else.   I'm not sure where the problem might be if not for the pagination code.